# php exec return error code 1

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, exec

I am using `exec()` to call python script. It return error code 1, but I type it on terminal is okay.

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Here is my php `exec()` content :

```
exec("sudo python /path/to/python.py --videoId $link", $output, $return);
```

I use `visudo` to set www-data can get root.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /path/to/upload.php
```

Did I miss something have to set or the code is wrong?

Comment: Your sudoers file should allow www-data user to run the python script as root, not just the php script.

Comment: The same way you set the PHP script to run as root, with visudo. But then just add `python /opt/SuperBlinder/superYoutuber.py` as well.

Comment: like this? `www-data ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /opt/SuperBlinder/superYoutuber.py`

Comment: No, be sure to add the full path to Python as well. Probably goes for the PHP line as well (unless the scripts are executable by themselves (+x chmod flag)).

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the command line and check the ouput!

Comment: I add `2>&1`, it return `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.   I am trying to figure out what python version did I use..  There are too many version on this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just simply change

```
www-data ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /path/to/upload.php
```

To

```
www-data ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And it can work. But I think this is not best answer.